# Android monthly reminder application

Tags: android

i am creating an application where one needs to stored recurring reminders in the database. i have stored the reminder record in the database where user mentions on what day of every month he will have to perform his task in a table named alert. now i want some service which can remind user every month about this task on the day set by the user. i have looked into alarm manager and other options but can not figure out some concrete way. can some one help me out here?
every thing is done. i am stuck on this last hurdle. my application launch is stuck because of this one pending task. can any one help?

thanks a lot,
Navraj singh

Comment: "i have looked into alarm manager and other options but can not figure out some concrete way." -- Then look at `AlarmManager` again, since it is the correct answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I would not rely on it for one month schedule ;)

Comment: @Laurent': Perhaps not, but I would rely on it for a daily schedule, where you then set an alarm if an event will occur in the next 24 hours.

Comment: its not a single event its about activities that we perform every month. say some one has a doctors appointment on 5th day of every month. so he just specifies a date in order to stay informed. i believe that makes a

Comment: @CommonsWare You can't rely on the AlarmManager even for a daily schedule unless: 

1) You make sure to restart it on boot.

2) You rely on the fact that task killers won't kill it (by calling restartPackage (which is now deprecated, but still available on Froyo and below if I'm not mistaken)).

Answer (score 0):

A very good example for your application

visit http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

```
    public void startAlert(View view) {
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);// In this text box
            //you will give the time in seconds you can change it according to your 
            //need.Like getting this text from database as you need.
    int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Above function start the alarm after the given time.

Here s the Broadcast receiver class

```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)    

            context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
}

 }
```

Comment: Because setting up an Alarm one month ahead is quiet unreliable (e.g. phone is shut down), I would set up a daily alarm and check if something is scheduled for this particular day. Don't forget to reset it after a reboot.

Comment: And what `MyBroadcastReceiver.class` includes ? What to do when the Alarm is triggered ??? Thanks for answering.

Comment: @cpyressious: "Because setting up an Alarm one month ahead is quiet unreliable (e.g. phone is shut down)" -- you have to deal with that for an alarm that goes off every 5 minutes, too. "Phone shut down" and "reboot" are the same operation, after all.

Comment: its not a single event its about activities that we perform every month. say some one has a doctors appointment on 5th day of every month. so he just specifies a date in order to stay informed. i believe that makes a perfect sense. so this alarm is not for one time. but for once every month. thats why i think its different.